# Is there a Python or Excel function to convert a single character to multiple characters?

Tags: python, excel

I have a list of IP addresses which contain a wildcard character (i.e., a `"*"`).  An example would be `10.20.*.*` or `10.*.*.*` or `192.168.20.*`

How do I convert the IP addresses to proper IP addresses?

For example, `10.20.*.*` would be `10.20.0.0`, `10.20.0.1`, `10.20.0.2...10.20.255.255` (hundreds of thousands of individual IP addresses).  I am attempting to convert a system which allows wildcards to a system which requires individual IP addresses.

I have tried to use search and replace in a text file, using RegEx, but it did not work as expected

Comment: Are those only implicit endings or can the wildcard be somewhere in the middle? https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html netaddr package deals nicely with ip addresses and networks and IPNetwork constructor allows implicit ends.

Comment: can you post your existing code?

Comment: Your 2nd example `10.*.*.*` will return `255^3` results which means, if you are storing this in Excel, you will have a requirement for multiple columns just for the `10.` group.  Perhaps, if you are going to use Excel, you should consider one worksheet per IP Network Class, or some similar scheme

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import itertools

ip = "10.0.*.*"

output = [[int(x)] if x != '*' else [i for i in range(256)] for x in ip.split(".")]
print(list(itertools.product(*output)))

# >> [(10, 0, 0, 0), (10, 0, 0, 1), (10, 0, 0, 2), ..., (10, 0, 255, 254), (10, 0, 255, 255)]
```

> More here: [list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) and [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) library

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) library.

```py
def ip_range(wildcard):
    mask = 32 - wildcard.count('*') * 8
    network = ipaddress.ip_network('{}/{}'.format(wildcard.replace('*', '0'), mask))
    return network.hosts()
```

This function will return generator of `ipaddress.IPv4Address` objects.

Usage:

```
>>> ip_range('10.0.0.*')
<generator object _BaseNetwork.hosts at 0x105ece7c8>
>>> list(map(str, _))
['10.0.0.1',
 '10.0.0.2',
 '10.0.0.3',
 ...
 '10.0.0.253',
 '10.0.0.254']
```